# How to form post from C#

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've an aspx form with a form tag as below and this form tag contains some sensitive info with hidden fields

```
    <form id="payment_confirmation" target="myFrame" action='https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/embedded/pay' method="post"/>

     <input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="sensitivevalue1">
        <input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="sensitivevalue2">
        <input type="hidden" name="transaction_uuid" value="<% Response.Write(getUUID()); %>">
        <input type="hidden" name="signed_field_names" value="sensitivevalue3">
        <input type="hidden" name="unsigned_field_names" value="card_type,card_number,card_expiry_date">
        <input type="hidden" name="signed_date_time" value="<% Response.Write(getUTCDateTime()); %>">
        <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en">

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

When i click "Submit" it successfully post the values and user is "redirected" into the "https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/embedded/pay" form but those hidden fields values are exposed to users (when they inspect the page). I can encrypt them but is there any other way i can post values and redirect from backend where values will not be exposed to users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  Hidden fields are only hidden from view on the screen and will always be available be available when viewing the source of the page when you are using web forms like this.  You can use the viewstate, which will encode the fields and make them harder to read, but if it is truly sensitive information, you will need to properly encrypt that information.

Hope that helps.